# Pass multiple cookies value as variables from background.js to contentscript.js

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get cookies values with this background.js

```
var myUrl = "https://cookiedomain.com/";

chrome.cookies.get({url: myUrl, name: 'email'}, function(cookie) {
     var email = cookie.value;
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ data: email });
});

chrome.cookies.get({url: myUrl, name: 'password'}, function(cookie) {
     var password = cookie.value;
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ data: password });
});
```

and get email, password as variables in content.js

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      var email = request.email;
      var password = request.password;
    });

  ....

document.getElementById('id').value = email;

document.getElementById('id1').value = password ;
```

but seems not working, can anyone help me with that?

thanks to all.

Comment: what `chrome.cookies.getAll()` has as result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code: chrome.**tabs**.sendMessage should have been used with a tab id, the two document.getElementById lines should have been inside the onMessage callback, your background script was sending an object with `data` property inside, but the content script was expecting `email` and `password`.

There's a simpler approach: reverse the flow and let the content script make the request to the background script, which will get both cookies and send them back in a single response.

background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.topic === 'getAuth') {
    chrome.cookies.get({url: msg.url, name: 'email'}, ({value: email}) => {
      chrome.cookies.get({url: msg.url, name: 'password'}, ({value: password}) => {
        sendResponse({email, password});
      });
    });
    // keep sendResponse channel open
    return true;
  }
});
```

content script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  topic: 'getAuth',
  url: location.href,
}, ({email, password}) => {
  document.getElementById('id').value = email;
  document.getElementById('id1').value = password;
});
```